# Curator framework for zookeeper - Interprocess mutex takes 50ms to acquire lock each time

Tags: redis, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using Curator framework Interprocess mutex for creating distributed lock to reserve some resource.  However, I can see that zookeeper takes 50-100 ms each time to acquire a lock and 20-40 ms for releasing locks. 
My application is write-heavy and has to respond within 500 ms for 10-50 req/second and I can't afford to give 70-140 ms on just acquiring and releasing lock.
1) Is there is any way I can improve this? My zookeeper server and the client are on the same host.
I have tried taking care of setting up the zookeeper server as mentioned in the administrative guide.
2) Should I use some other framework/technology for it. I was wondering if Redis SETNX would be a better solution or using Chubby.

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper is primarily designed to be consistent and secondly to be fast. Consistency comes with the cost of coordination. That will always add latencies. What you *could* do is to do sharding based on your work and only do worker-level locking. That would avoid the additional cost of Zookeeper locks at the expense of adding complexity when adding or removing workers.